# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. (System.Data.SQLClient)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, database-connection, sqlclient

I tried to look at the data connection between my visual studio and SQL server, however it keeps on saying "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed." How can I get this fixed please? It was working before, suddenly it stopped working. I checked in the C:/windows/assembly System.Data.SQLClient is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the provider factory is [registered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with an appropriate entry in the machine.config.

Comment: Is there a way I can reset my machine config

Comment: you do not need to reset the machine.config. Just locate the 'DbProviderFactories' node (add it if it is missing) and add the node for the System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was selecting the worng reference. For some reason x86 works, while x64 does not (in my case). Simply don't forget to reference `System.Data.SQLite.dll` and/or `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll`.