# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having problem in running my ASP.Net MVC project which is an admin project. It connects with a sql server database to fetch record. When I try to build and run, I am welcomed with this error: **"Unable to find requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed"**.
[Here is the link to this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTs4C.png)

I have tried many solutions available on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me that's why I am posting this question here again. I tried changing the Target Framework version in Properties of project to all the available versions but all in vain. [Here is the screenshot of my Global.asax.cs file which is causing this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USU9S.png).

Below is the connection string of my project:

```
<add name="AlkhaleejEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Alkhaleej;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Comment: Did you try fresh install of Sql server provider as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn538994(v=sql.120).aspx) ?

Comment: Dear #SivaGopal ! I tried installing Sql Server provider from the link you provided, restarted my system  and visual studio. Then I 've re-run my project but same exception is there once again :( .

Comment: Did you already installed 'EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact'? Or you can provide us the list of things you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection string provided above indicates EF connection provider being used:

```
connectionString="metadata=res:///Models.Model1.csdl|res:///Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.;initial catalog=Alkhaleej;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

Note that `SimpleMembershipProvider` can't use EF provider connection string (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20019035/6378815)) due to usage of `SqlClient` provider instead of `EntityClient`, hence it requires SQL Server connection string to interact with database.

Try open `Server Explorer` => `Data Connections` => right click your server connection, select `Properties` => add provided SQL Server connection string something like this one (leave EF connection string part as is, *just add SqlClient provider connection string*):

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Alkhaleej;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then, change `connectionStringName` parameter on `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` method inside `SimpleMembershipInitializer` class to SQL Server connection string name as given below:

```
public class SimpleMembershipInitializer
{
    public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
    {
        // other code part

        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
        }
    }
}
```

NB: The ideal setup for EF projects should include at least one `SqlClient` connection string and one `EntityClient` connection string, which may serve different providers with same target database.

Similar issues:

[SimpleMembershipInitializer won't initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902685/simplemembershipinitializer-wont-initialize)

[Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. (SqlClient)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205400/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-sqlclient)

[Can SimpleMembership and Entity Framework share a connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000869/can-simplemembership-and-entity-framework-share-a-connection-string)